# Date field not rendering correctly through extra.tpl file

Tags: extension, scheduled-job

We have one custom extension which try to add additional field on scheduled job New/Edit screen using hook.

```
    function jobextra_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
      if ($formName == 'CRM_Admin_Form_Job') {
        $form->add('datepicker', 'job_date_time_start', ts('Date & Time Start'), NULL, FALSE, ['minDate' => date('Y-m-d')]);
        $form->add('datepicker', 'job_date_time_end', ts('Date & Time End'), NULL, FALSE, ['minDate' => date('Y-m-d')]);
        // there are other non date related field
      }
    }
```

and supporting extra.tpl file `templates/CRM/Admin/Page/Job.extra.tpl`

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
    CRM.$(document).ready(function() {
        CRM.$('.crm-job-form-block-name_job_date_time_end').insertAfter('.crm-job-form-block-run_frequency');
        CRM.$('.crm-job-form-block-name_job_date_time_start').insertAfter('.crm-job-form-block-run_frequency');
         // other fields are inserted...
    });

</script>
{/literal}
<table style="display:none;">
    <tr class="crm-job-form-block-name_job_date_time_start" style="">
        <td class="label">{$form.job_date_time_start.label}</td>
        <td>{$form.job_date_time_start.html}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="crm-job-form-block-name_job_date_time_end" style="">
        <td class="label">{$form.job_date_time_end.label}</td>
        <td>{$form.job_date_time_end.html}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Date field is not rendering correctly, instead of showing date picker field and time field, i am just seeing simple textfield.

If i put these 2 field into core `templates/CRM/Admin/Form/Job.tpl`, both field rendered correctly.

Since this is in `extra.tpl` , tpl file load outside `crm-container`, and then we moving these field using jQuery into right position inside `crm-container`.

that may be issue?.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize datepicker field

```
$('input[name="job_date_time_end"]').datepicker();
```